# Does ImageMagick decrease image quality by default?

Tags: imagemagick

I use ImageMagick to convert images from one format to another, to convert them into a single PDF, to rotate them according to camera orientation, to trim white space, or sometimes to change resolution.

When doing these tasks, I never want to decrease image quality. I would always prefer to preserve the quality as high as possible.

The description of the [`-quality`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) parameter confuses me. If I understood its description correctly, ImageMagick always slightly decreases the image quality during conversions.

Is it really so? Does it mean I should use `-quality 100` as a safety belt each time I use ImageMagick?

Comment: Imagemagick keeps quality of most image formats except JPG. JPG is a lossy compression format even at quality 100. Imagemagick will keep the quality setting if one exists, if there is no quality setting and you save to JPG, then it defaults to 92. I suspect that is because the quality is not much different from 100, but the speed of processing is better. Also note that -quality values are set different for PNG than for JPG.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks. So, if one is a perfectionist, he/she should use `-quality 100` when converting into JPEG and don't use the `-quality` parameter otherwise, right?

Comment: No, -quality 100 is still going to be lossy.  Also it depends upon your needs. If file size is important, one may want to give up quality (especially if it is not terribly visible) to have a smaller file size.  Also -quality 100 would mean something totally different for PNG and may not be the best quality value to use to get good compression (file size).  However, PNG is not lossy and no matter what file size you have from the compression, it will be reversible back to the original uncompressed quality.

Comment: Well, I do understand `-quality 100` is still lossy, because this is how JPEG format works. Then, you awaring me from using `-quality 100` when converting into PNG, but note that I said that I'm going to use it when converting to JPEG only... So I don't really see any contradictions in your previous comment and in mine...

Comment: If you want the best quality from JPG, then yes, you can use -quality 100 if you are not concerned about file size.  If you want it lossless, then use JP2.